# Make Spring use Jackson to convert JSON encoded @RequestParam in GET endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

This is my first question in stackoverflow ever, so please be gentle :)

There is an existing GET endpoint which be converted into POST.
It needs to be extended to accept a query parameter `filterKeys` which will contain JSON encoded data. This approach is not very common, but it is being used by some big APIs.
The working approach is to map the query parameter to a String and then deserialised to a Java object by using the Jackson ObjectMapper within the controller method.
Is there any way to apply this Jackson deserialisation somewhere in the background, just like it's supported for `@RequestBody` out of the box by Spring?

An example for the JSON encoded `filterKeys`:

```
[
  {
    "parameter": "datetime",
    "value": {
      "type": "INT_RANGE",
      "start": 1275782400,
      "end": 1571443199
    }
  },
  {
    "parameter": "value",
    "value": {
      "type": "LONG_RANGE",
      "start": 100,
      "end": 200
    }
  }
]
```

The Java object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude
public class FilterKeyRequest {

    @NotNull
    private String parameter;
    @NotNull
    private FilterValue value;

}
```

I tried simply mapping `filterKeys` to `FilterKeyRequest` which of course doesn't work.
The current solution is to do the deserialisation inside the controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/data")
public List<TransferResponse> getData(@RequestParam(required = false) int someOtherParam,
                                          @RequestParam(required = false) String filterKeys) throws BadFilterKeyParameter {

        List<FilterKeyRequest> filters = List.of();
        try {
            filters = objectMapper.readValue(filterKeys, new TypeReference<List<FilterKeyRequest>>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new BadFilterKeyParameter("The filterKeys parameters couldn't be encoded due do bad JSON format");
        }

        return someService.getData(someOtherParam, filters);
    }
```

I would really like to handle this elegantly somewhere in the background. It might be possible with `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` or `org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` somehow. Preferably without explicitly invoking of the Jackson object mapper.

UPDATE:
I found a solution with a `Converter`, but it still means explicitly invoking the Jackson `ObjectMapper`, but I can live with that:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class FilterKeyConverter implements Converter<String, List<FilterKeyRequest>> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public List<FilterKeyRequest> convert(String source) {
        List<FilterKeyRequest> filters = List.of();
        try {
            filters = mapper.readValue(source, new TypeReference<List<FilterKeyRequest>>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("The parameter couldn't be encoded due do bad JSON encoding");
        }
        return filters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getData() method should be defined inside a @RestController-annotated class (and **not** @Controller)

```
@RestController
public DataController {
    @GetMapping("/data")
    public List<TransferResponse> getData(@RequestParam(required = false) int someOtherParam,
                                          @RequestParam(required = false) String filterKeys) throws BadFilterKeyParameter {

        List<FilterKeyRequest> filters = List.of();
        try {
            filters = objectMapper.readValue(filterKeys, new TypeReference<List<FilterKeyRequest>>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new BadFilterKeyParameter("The filterKeys parameters couldn't be encoded due do bad JSON format");
        }

        return someService.getData(someOtherParam, filters);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is already in a class annotated with `@RestController` otherwise it wouldn't work without the `@ResponseBody` annotation, which is missing in my method (on purpose). Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's not related to my issue. The `@RestController` only removes the need for the `@ResponseBody` (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) and I'm trying to deserialise a JSON from a request parameter. The serialisation of the response always worked.

Comment: @Raif, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Spring will try to convert request parameters quite generically. If I have a request parameter holding JSON, I usually end up defining it as Map<String, Object> in the controller method.